# Assembly.CreateInstance and security

Tags: c#, security, scripting

I'm toying around with the idea of using C#'s ability to compile code on-demand as the basis of a scripting language. I was wondering, how can I sandbox the scripts that I am executing so that they cannot access the file system, network, etc. Basically, I want restricted permissions on the script being run.

Steps that I take:

```
CompilerResults r = CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(source);

Assembly a = r.CompiledAssembly;

IScript s = a.CreateInstance(...);

s.EntryPoint(...);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach for this is to execute the suspect code in a [sandboxed appdomain](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/08/08/449050.aspx).  Several reasons are given at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/04/19/579066.aspx, and an even more important one is that most of the other potential approaches are deprecated as of .NET 4.0.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit: disregard that, it's not safe!**

Check out `System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission` (and subclasses like [FileIOPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx)) and [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288469%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). If you want to temporary deny code from doing unsafe actions, you can use statements like this:

```
NamedPermissionSet ps = new NamedPermissionSet("Nothing");
ps.Deny();
CallYourScriptHere();
CodeAccessPermission.RevertAll();
```

Comment: Is there anything stopping CallyourScriptHere() from reverting all permissions set by your example?

Comment: `RevertAll` reverts CAS permissions set in current stack frame only, so calling it in `CallYourScriptHere` would only undo changes made in that method.

Comment: This is not effective protection against potentially malicious code.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/02/02/523390.aspx for why stack walk modifiers should not be used for sandboxing.